# Spotlight search stopped working after upgrading to iOS 13

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an iPhone 8 Plus phone and I installed iOS 13. Ever since I am always updating to the latest version of iOS 13. Regardless, the spotlight search does not work on my phone.

This is my main way of locating apps on the phone, so this issue is particularly painful. Here is what I do:

- Swipe down on the home screen.
- Start typing the name of the app, for example, "App Store"
- Nothing happens, the result list does not update while typing. The **Siri Suggestions** part of the screen just remains the same.
- Hit the **Search** button on the keyboard
- Again, nothing happens. The **Siri Suggestions** list is not updated.

I tried restarting the phone on several occasions but did not help. I am also installing the latest update. As of now, the version I have is 13.1.13.

I tried this with other phones with iOS 13, but they did not have this problem.

Any ideas, what I can try to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

If your search is showing empty search results, try these as best and first solution:

1. Tap **Settings** > **General** > **Language & Region** > iPad Language or iPhone Language
2. Select a language (e.g.; Canada English) and tap Done. Then confirm your change by tapping Continue.
3. Now change back to your original language.

If you think that Search is still not finding items, meaning it is not working correctly, try these steps:

1. Go to **Settings** > **Siri & Search**
2. Turn off (deactivate) everything (search results) by being on each App
3. Now turn off your device by pressing and holding the on/off button until you see the slider. Then slide the red slider.
4. Turn your device on.
5. Now go to **Settings** > **Siri & Search** and now turn everything on.**

Comment: I tried both methods. unfortunately, none of them helped. I am guessing that maybe a device reset and restoring from backup would help me.

Comment: A device reset can also help. But generally, the first step helped few of my colleagues who face similar issues.

Comment: I updated to the latest iOS version which is 13.1.3 but it still not works. I will try once again the language change and report back. I also add some details to my original question like the new version number and the name of the panel that shows the app results are called Siri Suggestions

Comment: I still have no solution here, so I go ahead and do the hard-reset as this is becoming super annoying :(

Comment: I have the exact same issue. None of the solutions helped... and I'm sick of resetting my device every two month when a new bug pops up.

Comment: Now, the search works but occasionally it stops. I can say the situation is improved, but not 100%. It is annoying but I am not sure what else I can do other than resetting my phone, which is not ideal because I need to re-register some of my apps after each reset.

Comment: My spotlight was completely blurry after updating to ios14 - changing to Canadian English, restarting worked. I now set back to uk